# Presenting XML data Ruby - Alternatives to tables?

Tags: ruby, xml, html

I've got an XML file holding data - names and times. I'm using Ruby to display this in a web page as a time-table. I have no problems in parsing the data.

Currently, I'm trying to use colspans and rowspans to display the data correctly - but this feels like an awful silly way of dealing with this data. Imagine timeline as headers - names as row headers.

example data: 
Name: John
Start: 8.00pm
End: 11.00pm

Name: Ellie
Start: 11.30pm
End: 1.00am

Should I be using data-attributes on divs or something similar, rather than creating lots of empty TDs of different colspans. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a good rule of thumb is to not use tables for formatting. I would refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html) for some good explanations on this.

That being said, I would recommend divs over tables. Yes, it does require a bit more CSS knowledge as you have to deal with floating divs and what not, but once you get the hang of it, you won't look back.